# How can I avoid the "grep: Argument list too long" error?

Tags: bash, script, grep, xargs

I'm using Mac 10.7.5 and on a bash shell.  I'm trying to find instances of a string in a group of files but keep getting this error

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:folder davea$ find . -name "*" | xargs grep 'state-icons'
xargs: grep: Argument list too long
```

How can I run the command (or a similar one) to avoid this error?

Comment: `grep '...' <( find … )` maybe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `-n` option of `xargs` to limit the number of arguments.

```
find . -name "*" | xargs -n 20 grep 'state-icons'
```

But a better solution is to use `-type f` instead of `-name "*"` in order to limit the list to ordinary files, avoiding the error message for each folder.

Note that it does not work for files with whitespace in their names.

Comment: Would limiting the number of arguments potentially prevent the correct results from being displayed?  Ultimately my goal is to find files with an instance of the desired string, as opposed to simply eliminating the error message.

Comment: @Dave: No, `grep` will be run several times, with 20 file arguments each. You might add `-type f` to `find` to avoid errors when `grep` tries to open directories.

Comment: There’s a risk that if the `find` reports, say, 61 files, then `xargs` will run `grep` four times –– three times with 20 files and once with 1 file.  When `grep` is run with multiple files, it reports the name(s) of the file(s) where it finds matches; not so with only one filename argument.  A trick that is commonly used to fix this is to say `xargs -n 20 grep 'state-icons' /dev/null`, so `xargs` will run `grep` three times with 21 files and once with 2 files –– the additional file, of course, being `/dev/null`, which will otherwise have no effect on the run.

Comment: @Scott: You can also use the `-H` option of `grep` (if supported).

Comment: @choroba: I don't have a Mac and I didn't have one seven years ago either. But on my machine it prints an error to stderr for each directory but it does print the filenames on stdout. What failure did you experience?

Comment: @choroba: the answer says "Note that it does not work for files with whitespace in their names."

Comment: @choroba: i don't remember the context of that comment but it was probably a response to something; otherwise I would have edited the answer, which is correct. Anyway, I deleted it.

Answer (score -2):

What about this if you want to seach through the **filename**:

```
for x in ./**/*.*; do echo "$x" | grep 'state-icons' ; done
```

and this if you want to seach through the **file content**:

```
for x in ./**/*.*; do grep 'state-icons' "$x" ; done
```

Comment: That would run ``grep`` only on the file *names,* not on their contents.  Also, `*.*` does not mean “all files” (as it does in Windows); it restricts the search to files that have a **`.`** in their name.

Comment: @Scott but the `-name` argument indicates that they want to search about the filename. If they want to search about the file content, just omit the `echo` and use `grep 'state-icons' $x`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include that variation.   Oh, and I almost forgot: please quote your variables.